# Scipy using PyCall in Julia

Tags: python, scipy, julia

I have a moderately large system of non-linear equations that I want to solve using scipy.optimize in Julia. The problem is that I store the equations in a vector before I pass them to the solver and PyCall doesn't accept that. For example these methods both work:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport scipy.optimize as so

function F(x)
 f1=1- x[1] - x[2]
 f2=8 - x[1] - 3*x[2]
 return f1, f2
end

x0 = [1,1]
x = so.fsolve(F, x0)

function G(x)
 f=[1 - x[1] - x[2],
    8 - x[1] - 3*x[2]]
 return f
end

x0 = [1,1]
x = so.fsolve(G, x0)
```

However this does not:

```
function H(x)
 f[1]=1 - x[1] - x[2]
 f[2]=8 - x[1] - 3*x[2]
 return f
end

x0 = [1,1]
x = so.fsolve(H, x0)
```

Neither does this:

```
function P(x)
 f[1]= 1 - x[1] - x[2]
 f[2]= 8 - x[1] - 3*x[2]
 return f[1], f[2]
end

x0 = [1,1]
x = so.fsolve(P, x0)
```

I don't think it's feasible to not use a loop because of the nature of the problem. Is there any way to return the vector in a way that fsolve can accept it?

Answer (score 7):

The second two methods never create `f` which is the issue. You have to create the array first.

```
function H(x)
 f = similar(x)
 f[1]=1 - x[1] - x[2]
 f[2]=8 - x[1] - 3*x[2]
 return f
end
```

which will automatically match the size and type of `x`, or you can use the constructor:

```
function H(x)
 f = Vector{Float64}(2)
 f[1]=1 - x[1] - x[2]
 f[2]=8 - x[1] - 3*x[2]
 return f
end
```

However you want to do it, you need to make the array. `P` has the same problem.

Also, you should checkout NLSolve.jl. It allows a pre-allocated form:

```
function H(x,f)
 f[1]=1 - x[1] - x[2]
 f[2]=8 - x[1] - 3*x[2]
 return nothing
end
```

which should allocate less and do better. Roots.jl is another good Julia option.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did try NLSolve and I wasn't sure why I have to include the f vector in the H(x,f). Now it became clear.

The issue that I had with NLSolve was that it didn't converge even if I gave as initial guess the solution I obtained from Matlab.

Comment: I would open up another question about that. I would suspect there was an error in your code.